# How to create a dialog with three custom buttons to choose?

Tags: android, list, android-layout, button, customdialog

I am trying to create a dialog like this but only with three clickable colored Buttons

[image]

When you click on a color the dialog goes away and the choosen button appears on the main screen

I currently have only three xml files for the different buttons and I don't know how to continue.

I'm thinking of creating a single choice list dialog, but I'm not sure if it is possible to show the three buttons horizontally and instead of a text to show the buttons.

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: You could use 3 TextViews, with a circular Shape inside. Since TextViews respond to clicks, you're pretty much done!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking of creating a single choice list dialog, but I'm not sure
>   if it is possible to show the three buttons horizontally and instead
>   of a text to show the buttons.

It's not possible, and the implementation could vary among OS versions or manufacturers anyway.

You will want to create your own xml layout and create a custom DialogFragment that inflates your xml layout in `DialogFragment.onCreateView()`.

**dialog_color_button_picker.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    ... however you want to do your layout ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**ColorButtonPickerDialog.kt**

```
class ColorButtonPickerDialog: DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_color_button_picker, container, false)
    }
}
```

Within `ColorButtonPickerDialog.onCreateView()` you can then reference your views by id and add listeners just like you would with a normal fragment.